# getting SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer (This isn't spam and i don't have other people mistakes who posted the same question)

Tags: javascript, web

I just started learning js.
And I run to this exception: SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer

This is my code:

```
const movie = {
    title: 'a',
    releaseYear = 2018,
    rating: 4.5,
    director: 'b'
};
showProperties(movie);

function showProperties(obj){
    for (let key in obj){
        if (typeof obj[key] === 'string')
            console.log(key, obj[key]);
    }
}
```

What is wrong with this code? I checked other people who got this error on their js code but i didn't have none of their mistakes.

What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: `releaseYear = 2018` should be `releaseYear: 2018`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right Code :

const movie = {
title: 'a',
releaseYear: 2018,
rating: 4.5,
director: 'b'
};

hi
you have to use : instead = in line 3.
That's why it happened